Sub verb agreement

Father, mother and children (make/makes) a family.

Which verb should I use here, make or makes, as family is a collective noun in singular form?

Father, mother, and children, considered as categories of relative, are three things, grammatically speaking. So plural verb.

I don't see voting to close as "proofreading" to be justified. There's only one sentence, and a clear source of concern is identified and explained. If the existing close reasons don't fit well, feel free to use custom ones. But I don't see that this is off topic.

The number of the verb should match the subject—in this case, "father, mother, and children."
A similar sentence might be "Bob and Jane start a club." The verb is plural because the subject is compound.

So, you think it is father, mother and children make, ri8?

@PoojaMathew Yes; the subject is those three words. "Family" is the object.
